# Cast struct em struct

Tags: c

Galera estou usando sockets no windows

e quando chego na funçao connect

tenho o sequinte parametro:

(struct sockaddr *)&server(que é meu socket)

como funciona esse cast?

Comment: Não crie várias perguntas, você pode editar a sua [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83303/cast-struct-para-struct-em-c) e dar os detalhes lá.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta curta é que as funções de socket esperam uma estrutura sockaddr, mas você está tipicamente passando uma estrutura sockaddr_in, sockaddr_un, ou de outro tipo.

Os métodos de socket funcionam para inúmeras tecnologias de rede (Internet, Internet IPv6, Ethernet, Unix Sockets) e cada tecnologia tem uma estrutura diferente para descrever um endereço de rede.

A estrutura sockaddr "genérica" só o membro sa_family, cujo valor identifica o tipo de endereço, e mais 14 bytes de enchimento que vão ser utilizados pelas estruturas especializadas. Por exemplo, a estrutura sockaddr_in tem apenas 7 bytes uteis: sa_family = AF_INET, porta e endereço IP.

Isto acontece porque a linguagem C não tem o conceito de classes e herança. Se tivesse, se fosse C++, sockaddr_in poderia ser uma subclasse de sockaddr, e as funções aceitariam sockaddr_in sem o cast.